# I'm including <cmath> but can't compile std::abs(double)

Tags: c++, stl, include, c++builder

After re-installing Rad-Studio XE2 I'm finding that some code that used to compile no longer works. For example I get a compiler error on the following:

```
#include <cmath>

void MyClass::Rotate(double RotAngle){
  bool NotRotated = std::abs(RotAngle) < 1;
  ... do something
}
```

with the following error:

```
[BCC32 Error] XXX.cpp(38): E2015 Ambiguity between 'std::abs(int) at c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\9.0\include\windows\crtl\stdlib.h:142' and 'std::abs(__int64) at c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\rad studio\9.0\include\windows\crtl\stdlib.h:538'
```

This code used to compile, and obviously should, so what am I missing? Rad_studio has had all updates applied..

Comment: Have you tried explicitly casting RotAngle as int or __int64 when passing it to abs?

Answer (score 1):

In this case we actually can learn a lot from the standard.

C++98: In 26.5/Table 80 and 81 we learn that `abs` is in `<cstdlib>` and NOT `<cmath>`. But then in 26.5 we have the contradictory statement `In addition to the double versions of the math functions in <cmath>, C++ adds float and long
double overloaded versions of these functions, with the same semantics.` which then lists `abs` as having additional overloads in `<cmath>` where the preceeding table said it should not be.

This is actually fixed in C++11 where 26.8/Table 119 clearly shows `abs` as a member of `<cmath>` *as well as* in `<cstdlib>` (although the added overloads for floating point types still appear exclusive to `<cmath>`.

As for your problem there are two likely situations:

1. You were compiling as C++11 before and are no longer doing so.
2. You were compiling C++98/03 but your standard libraries were updated to a version where `<cmath>` no longer implicitly includes `<cstdlib>` *and* your compiler was based on the table requirements rather than the implicit requirements of 26.5.

Most likely including `<cstdlib>` would fix the problem as would compiling in C++11 mode.

Comment: as far as I can tell XE2 is c++98 only. I've tried including both files and the problem remains.